# Extracting part of names in a vector list

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have the following vector of directories.

```
c("", "Dia 04", "Dia 04/Basler_2020-11-04 13_08_41.568967_bg", 
"Dia 04/Basler_2020-11-04 13_08_41.568967_frames", "Dia 04/Basler_2020-11-04 13_38_46.380957_bg", 
"Dia 04/Basler_2020-11-04 13_38_46.380957_frames", "Dia 04/Basler_2020-11-04 14_08_51.133352_bg", 
"Dia 04/Basler_2020-11-04 14_08_51.133352_frames", "Dia 04/Basler_2020-11-04 14_38_55.875411_bg", 
"Dia 04/Basler_2020-11-04 14_38_55.875411_frames")
```

I would like to get the `unique` names that start after the name "Basler_" until the name "_bg" or "_frames".

I try to use `pattern` in `list.dirs()` but wont works `list.dirs(path = ".", full.names = F, recursive = TRUE, pattern = '(?<=/Basler_).*(?=_bg)')`

output desired:

```
c("2020-11-04 13_08_41.568967", "2020-11-04 13_38_46.380957", "Basler_2020-11-04 14_08_51.133352", "2020-11-04 14_38_55.875411")
```

Thanks all

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this data:

```
names <- c("", "Dia 04", "Dia 04/Basler_2020-11-04 13_08_41.568967_bg", 
           "Dia 04/Basler_2020-11-04 13_08_41.568967_frames", "Dia 04/Basler_2020-11-04 13_38_46.380957_bg", 
           "Dia 04/Basler_2020-11-04 13_38_46.380957_frames", "Dia 04/Basler_2020-11-04 14_08_51.133352_bg", 
           "Dia 04/Basler_2020-11-04 14_08_51.133352_frames", "Dia 04/Basler_2020-11-04 14_38_55.875411_bg", 
           "Dia 04/Basler_2020-11-04 14_38_55.875411_frames")
```

You can use `str_extract`:

`base R`:

```
unique(str_extract(names, "(?<=Basler_)[\\d_. -]+(?=_bg)"))
```

`tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)
data.frame(names) %>%
  mutate(name_0 = str_extract(names, "(?<=Basler_)[\\d_. -]+(?=_bg)")) %>%
  pull(name_0) %>%
  unique(.)
[1] NA                           "2020-11-04 13_08_41.568967" "2020-11-04 13_38_46.380957" "2020-11-04 14_08_51.133352"
[5] "2020-11-04 14_38_55.875411"
```